# Django - Add Django Rest Swagger schema to DRF tagged functions with `@api_view`

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger

**Django - How to add swagger auto schema to DRF tagged functions with `@api_view`?**

I have this function

view.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@swagger_auto_schema(
    request_body=PostSerializer,
    operation_description="Create a post object"
)
def post_create_post(request):
```

[image]
But the request body data requirements aren't showing up in Swagger UI. How do you add swagger documentation to endpoints created using `@api_view`? Also I'd ideally like to add a list of parameters with their types to the swagger schema.

Comment: Additionally,  your operation description is not shown. It should be "Create a post object" instead of "POST endpoint for current user creating a goal update post"

Comment: You code snippet looks fine, can you please provide us with more code, e.g. routing code from `urls.py`  or `PostSerializer` implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is ordering

```
@swagger_auto_schema(
    method='post',
    request_body=PostSerializer,
    operation_description="Create a post object"
)
@api_view(['POST'])
def post_create_post(request):
```

you also need to add an `method` param to `@swagger_auto_schema`

Answer (score 0):

Decorators are applied first for those 'closest' to the function definition. In order to use the `@swagger_auto_schema` decorator, the `@api_view` decorator must first be applied.

Hence, the corrected version is:

```py
@swagger_auto_schema(
    request_body=PostSerializer,
    operation_description="Create a post object"
)
@api_view(['POST'])
def post_create_post(request):
```

Editorial: the other answer states:

> you also need to add an method param to @swagger_auto_schema

However, for routes which have only one method, it's not necessary to specify it, as [it will be assumed for you](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/blob/b99306f71c6a5779b62189df7d9c1f5ea1c794ef/src/drf_yasg/utils.py#L172-L174), at least in the current version of the drf_yasg library.