# Django - drf-yasg setting request_body in @swagger_auto_schema to reduced version of serializer on @api_view

Tags: python, django, drf-yasg

Is there a way to set `request_body` for `@swagger_auto_schema` to only be part of a Serializer? The reasoning being as you can see below the creator is set by the current user object passed by authenticator to the `post_create` view, but if I set `request_body` to the `PostSerializer` that'll be confusing for others, because they'll assume it needs a `creator` attribute, even though that's parsed from the user. Is there a way I can set `request_body` for this endpoint that uses `@api_view` with some of `PostSerializer`?

view.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@swagger_auto_schema(
    operation_description="Create a post object"
)
def post_create(request):
    try:
        request.data['creator'] = str(request.user.uuid)
        post_serializer = PostSerializer(data=request.data)

        if post_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            post_obj = post_serializer.save()

    except ValidationError as e:
        return Response(dict(error=str(e),
                             user_message=error_message_generic),
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    return Response(post_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

serializer.py

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('creator', 'body', 'uuid', 'created', 'updated_at')
```

Comment: Don't think so, but you can create a schema with the correct fields: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50929098/django-rest-framework-how-to-add-post-parameters-to-api-documentdrf-yasg

Comment: @NickODell for some reason I tried this and it doesn't show up when applied to an `@api_view` 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69565669/django-add-django-rest-swagger-schema-to-drf-tagged-functions-with-api-view

Comment: All of the drf-yasg documentation examples have the decorators in the other order. Have you tired putting `@swagger_auto_schema` first before `@api_view` ?

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is to implement a second Serializer with only the concerned subset of fields, Which would look like this :

```
class PostSerializerCreator(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        # Only include the user-provided fields
        fields = ('body', 'uuid', 'created', 'updated_at')
```

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@swagger_auto_schema(
    request_body=PostSerializerCreator,
    operation_description="Create a post object"
)
def post_create(request):
    try:
        request.data['creator'] = str(request.user.uuid)
        post_serializer = PostSerializer(data=request.data)

        if post_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            post_obj = post_serializer.save()

    except ValidationError as e:
        return Response(dict(error=str(e),
                             user_message=error_message_generic),
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    return Response(post_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

I suppose you should also remove other fields such as `updated_at` which should be computed at execution rather than being supplied by the API user.

Comment: Can't I create the new serializer fields as subsets of the original rather than remaking it?

Comment: Instead of explicitly specifing all fields to include, you can choose to only specify fields to exclude with `Meta.exclude` : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-which-fields-to-include

Comment: You can also define your fields with `fields = PostSerializer.Meta.fields `